# jQuery IIFE, interject on demand?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a IIFE that self-fires on load and recursively calls itself every 30 seconds to get any alerts the system may have written out.

This works fine.

```
(function GetAlerts() {
   setTimeout(function() {
     $.ajax({ url: "?DO=getalertcount", success: function(data) {
        //do DOM stuff with data            
    }, complete: GetAlerts });
  }, 30000);
})();
```

There are things I will do, such as stop a widget, that write to the alert queue.  As such, that should immediately trigger an alert to display, not wait up to 30 seconds for it to fire.  (sockets and long polling are not an option due to server constraints)

So, I want to call this GetAlerts() on demand in some fashion from the handler of the action (such as stopping the widget click event)

What is the proper way to on-demand call this so that

1. the 30 second loop is retained (or re-started after the on-demand interject)
2. I don't end up with multiple `setTimeout` loops running
3. I don't duplicate a ton of code (as there is a lot of DOM stuff that happens in the guts of the success

The things I tried such as calling the function by name, attempting to set the timeout to a global var and stopping the timeout all failed one of the above points or simply did not invoke at all.

Comment: We'd usually call that not a closure, but an IENFE - immediately executed named function expression.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi    I did a bit of research on that and ended up seeing `IIFE` which I think perhaps better describes what I have.  But, it still didn't lead me to a better answer of how to get inside that `timeout`.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you "demand" alerts while an ajax requests is currently running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `setTimeout` to the `success` handler and use `clearTimeout` keep single loop running.

A class with public `.poll` method might help:

```
function AlertManager() {
    var successCallback = function (data) {
        // Private ajax success handler
        //do DOM stuff with data 
        $('#responses').append('Polled!<br/>');
    },
    _poll = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/echo/json/",
            success: successCallback,
            complete: function () {
                timeoutId = setTimeout(_poll, timeoutMs);
            }
        });
    },
    timeoutId,
    timeoutMs = 5000;

    this.poll = function () {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        _poll();
    };
}
```

Take a look at the fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neustroev_ai/64on18zg/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant solution.   :)